# Как проверить запущен ли процесс?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Нужна функция, которая проверяет запущен ли определенный процесс в системе (Windows) и в зависимости от этого выполняет дальнейшие действия.

Схема такая:
если процесс запущен (program.exe, определение по имени), то ... , если нет то ...

Пробую сделать это через `subprocess`, но то что нужно пока не получается, какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787120/ и множество аналогичных тем там же.

Comment: @PinkTux Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться универсальным кроссплатформенным решением - [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) (`pip install psutil`).

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    print(name)
    if name == "program.exe":
        pass
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение мне подошло и оно компактное