# Открытые программы или список процессов в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Как в Python3 можно посмотреть открытые программы или процессы наподобие `tasklist` в командной строке, но чтобы я смог считать всё в переменную?
 Пишу бота для telegram, который отправит информацию о компьютере.

Comment: Я бы воспользовался библиотекой `psutil`. Либо [советом из англо-язычного SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить запущен ли процесс?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535683/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81)

Comment: Альтернативно (вместо бота), можно glances сервер запустить и [по http необходимую информацию запрашивать.](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/wiki/The-Glances-RESTFULL-JSON-API)

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
print(*[line.decode('cp866', 'ignore') for line in Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()])
```

out:

```
Имя образа                     PID Имя сессии          № сеанса       Память
 ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
 System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         4 КБ
 System                           4 Services                   0       300 КБ
 smss.exe                       336 Services                   0       320 КБ
 csrss.exe                      440 Services                   0     4 412 КБ
 wininit.exe                    524 Services                   0       576 КБ
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
import subprocess

print(*[line.split() for line in subprocess.check_output("tasklist").splitlines()])
```

Считывает из `tasklist`, и выводит информацию

Answer (score 0):

Вот код для вывода только имён процессов, там присутствуют и другие параметры, там не сложно, думаю разберётесь, в коде есть фильтрация для отсеивания системных процессов и процессов запущенных другим пользователем:

```
import psutil
# Получение списка всех процессов
all_processes = psutil.process_iter()

# Фильтруем список процессов, оставляя только процессы текущего пользователя
user_processes = [p for p in all_processes if p.username() == psutil.Process().username()]

# Фильтруем список процессов, оставляя только пользовательские процессы
user_processes = [p for p in user_processes if p.pid >= 1000]

# Выводим имена пользовательских процессов по одному на строку
for p in user_processes:
    print(p.name())
```